# solr query - need help in writing solr query

Tags: solr, pivot, solr4, facet

[image: Input and Output Data]

The input data (left table) contains three columns namely Date, Servicing Type and Customer ID. Both right tables are examples of output of Solr query for different time range.

I need to find Count of Customers who fall in the one of these categories -  1 Paid service, 2 Paid Service, 3 Paid Service...n Paid Service for different date range. 2 Sample outputs are given in right side. Also Customer Id is written adjacent to output for better understanding but Customer Id is not a part of actual output.

The Solr Query can use date range to select rows for different month.

How do I achieve the given output.

1. Do I need to add a derived column to Input Data which will be used in this complex query ?
2. Will Solr UDF help in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking for here. Sample data would be very helpful.

However, it sounds like you may be able to do what you are looking for with facets and/or facet.pivot. You should be able to run an fq filter on the date range you are interested in and then get facet pivot for customers/invoices or invoices/customers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just edited above to give more clarity:- "Compute Count of Customers who fall in the one of these categories - 1 Paid service, 2 Paid Service, 3 Paid Service...n Paid Service for different time period." The above image shows sample data.

Comment: @RohitSarewar what does your data look like in Solr?

Comment: I have shared exact data in the above image. Apart from this I need to understand what exactly you are asking for 1) Same Data in CSV and Schema.xml - so that you can replicate this scenario      2) Screenshot of my Solr UI showing same data. Please reply.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use SOLR facet to achieve the result you wanted. You can use facet.query along with facet field something like

```
facet.query=date:['Start date' TO 'End Date']&facet.field=customerId
```

and this will give you similar result.

You can use the facet.limit to restrict the result counts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But we need to consider servicing type (Paid or Free) as well.

Comment: Rohit, If i understood your question then service type can also be part of facet.query like normal solar query.